# Well-defined measure on algebra of modulo sets

Tags: measure-theory

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $E \subset \{0,1,...,n-1\}$ define the modulo set:

$$ A_{n,E} := \{ k \in \mathbb{Ν} : k \ (mod \ n) \in E \} .$$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra defined by the collection of all those modulo sets for any $n$ and $E$.

In this algebra, we define the measure $P: \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ by:

$$ P [A_{n,E}] := \frac{|E|}{n} .$$

Show that the measure is well-defined. (meaning that for any two equal sets, the measure is the same.)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I did some examples and I was trying to show that for different sets in $n_1,E_1$ and $n_2,E_2$ through the set equality we should get that $n_1$ is a multiple of $n_2$ and $|E_1|$ the same multiple of $|E_2|$ when $n_1>n_2$ but I didn't manage to prove it.

Comment: Intutionally, I guess yes but I don't know how to explicitly write a proof, If I am understanding it correct.